# how can i embed rcharts(nplot) into shiny with html file?

Tags: html, shiny, rcharts

i want embed a nplot into shiny,  the server.R like

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$testChart <- renderChart2({
n1<-nPlot(Freq ~ Var1, data=speedTable, type="discreteBarChart", color="blue")
n1$xAxis(axisLabel = "Heading")
n1$yAxis(axisLabel = "label", width = 40)
n1$set(title = "Title")
n1$addParams(dom = 'testChart') 
return(n1)

})
})
```

and my index.html like this:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/> 
</head>

<body>
  <br />
  <br />
  <hr />
<div class="rChart nvd3" id="testChart"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

but in the page dosenot show anything?
Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102372/r-shiny-app-with-rcharts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have to download [D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) and [NVD3](https://github.com/novus/nvd3) and include those into your HTML :

```
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="nv.d3.min.js"></script>
```

And for the graph do something like that :

```
<div id="testChart" class="shiny-html-output rChart nvd3"></div>
<style>.nvd3-svg { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; }</style>
```